# SQL how to display separate elements

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

```
declare @car varchar(max)='';
select @car+=QUOTENAME(Column)+',' from TABLE
set @car = SUBSTRING(@car, 1, len(@car)-1)
print @car
```

In the column `Column` I wish I could display the elements that are not duplicates.

I've been trying to make :

```
select **distinct** @car+=QUOTENAME(Column)+',' 
from TABLE
```

but it doesn't work.

How can I do ?

Thank you for your response

Comment: I don't follow what you're asking here. Perhaps some sample data and expected results will help us help you? Are you simply trying to make a delimited list of the distinct values in the column? What version of SQL Server, if so?

Comment: I was confused also, but if @Larnu is correct - it's something I've had to do many times.  [Believe I used a script like this](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/11/25/sql-server-comma-separated-values-csv-from-table-column/)

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (MyColumn VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO @Table (MyColumn) VALUES ('A'), ('A'), ('B');

DECLARE @message VARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @message = STUFF((
    SELECT DISTINCT [text()] = ',' + QUOTENAME(MyColumn)
    FROM @Table
    FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 1, '')

SELECT @message
```

The result will be: **"[A],[B]"**. Is it what you want?

Comment: The result will be: "[A], [B]". Is it what you want? as a result, I have "[A], [A], [B]" with "[" and "]"

Comment: If you want to get **[A], [A], [B]**, you should remove **DISTINCT** from this query.

Comment: No that's ok, only I have a column named "[[sql] admin]" and I get "[[sql]] admin]" instead.

Comment: Is to make a PIVOT at the end. **[[sql] admin]** = **[A]** and **[[sql]] admin]** = **[A]]**. 
this is the only column with a problem